# Custom class on JPA ID attribute and @PrePersist

Tags: java, jpa

I use JPA for a few years now.

### What does work so far

On a legacy project the "request" entity's IDs look like this:

```
R0000001
R0000002
```

I converted an oracle sequence to a table generator:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "requestid", columnDefinition = "varchar(10)")
@TableGenerator(pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME", valueColumnName = "SEQ_NUMBER",
    pkColumnValue = "REQUEST_ID", name = "REQUEST_ID", table = "APPSEQUENCES",
    allocationSize = 5)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "REQUEST_ID")
private String requestId;

@PrePersist
public void prependIdWithR() {
  if (null == this.requestId) {
    LOG.error("Could not prepend RequestId which is null!");
    return;
  }

  if (requestId.charAt(0) != "R") {
    final int parsedRequestId = Integer.parseInt(requestId);
    final String formattedId = String.format("A%07d", parsedRequestId);
    LOG.debug("RequestId changed: [{}] => [{}].",
        requestId,
        formattedId);
    this.requestId = formattedId;

    return;
  }
}
```

This works just fine.

### What won't work / requirement

Now, I'd like to have a RequestId object instead of a plain string, which is used throughout the code.

If I just add a `@Converter` to my Id and change the type to RequestId, the following happens:

- An Id is pulled from the Sequence table.
- The Converter is invoked (which fails on `<RequestId, String>`, because a `java.lang.Long` was generated
- then prepersist would have been invoked.

Actual exception thrown by JPA:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: An exception occurred while calling convertToEntityAttribute on converter class my.self.RequestIdConverter with value 26
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.converters.ConverterClass.convertDataValueToObjectValue(ConverterClass.java:126) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long incompatible with java.lang.String
    at my.self.RequestIdConverter.convertToEntityAttribute(RequestIdConverter.java:1) ~[classes/:version-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.converters.ConverterClass.convertDataValueToObjectValue(ConverterClass.java:124) ~[na:na]
```

This means: I need to have @PrePersist invoked BEFORE `@Convert` OR have a string returned from the table generator (not a Long).

Is this scenario even possible? I think I need to go with a String.

### What I found out so far

- If I used hibernate, that would have been possible due to custom generator classes (which could be a modified table generator, returning a string).
- There is no such thing in plain JPA
- The converter is invoked before `@PrePersist`. The Converter is a `<RequestId, String>`, because the existing Table's ID column is a `varchar(10)`.
- RequestId is a plain pojo object generated by immutables.github.io. It only has a `String getValue()` method.
- I cannot change the database column to another type.
- I cannot remove the prefix from existing records.
- I need to be able to read old records, which already have an 'R' prefix.

I could implement a converter with `<RequestId, Object>` instead and then see if the object is a Long or a String. Is this possible? I don't like the idea of  having an any-object-converter. And I doubt it worked because it means casting to RequestId.